# Unity tweak tool switcher shortcuts

Tags: 14.04

I am unable to swap the keys in unity-tweak-tool switcher for window switching and launcher switching. I am trying to put window switching on super-tab, and launcher switching on alt-tab. Compiz settings is not the correct tool for this since I am using the unity window management.

Attempting to disable all of them, and then input the correct key combinations does not yield any results.

I'm sure this answer is painfully obvious. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just having this problem myself. Seems Unity Tweak Tool is broken in this sense.

You can still get the desired effect by using CompizConfig Settings Manager.

To install CompizConfig Settings Manager, on your terminal:

`$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Then `alt-f2` and type `ccsm`

Once open, you need to look for the **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**, select the **Switcher** tab, and click on the key bindings you wish to change.

[image]

Voilà!